# Android Eclipse Error Log gone?

Tags: android, eclipse, error-log

I've been using Eclipse for Android for almost a year now.

Recently I updated to Eclipse Juno. That didn't go smoothly, so I d/l the Android ADT bundle and reinstalled everything. Got everything working, it builds and runs. AVD works too.

But the Error Log in Eclipse (not LogCat that's OK) is missing from "Windows -Show View-Error log". I looked in 'Others' and searched using the search box in that window. Also Alt+Shift+Q doesn't list it and Alt+shift+Q+L doesn't open it.

The log is there under .../.metadata/.log - and gets updated but it's not in the UI ?

I also installed the SDK on a machine that's never had Eclipse on it and same result.

Comment: I was able to fix this. I uninstalled JAVA JDK7 and Android ADT. (I have Windows 7x64) Download ADTx64 and Java7x64 and the error log is back. Not sure why this worked now but it does.

Comment: Hey it's gone again! Aug2014. Deleted dev folders, deleted .metadata folder in workspace, uninstalled Java and reinstalled with both latest. No go. Other that that it works fine, just missing error log view. (not log view)

Comment: Update, still gone so I installed the latest Eclipse-Luna and installed the Android ADT separately. All works fine.